# Vertical scrolled listview with images do not fit width of screen

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I'm new in WPF and I writing simple application now. I want to create the ListView with 3 columns in width and 3 rows in height for any count of elements, and searching over the web about 2 hours but can't find a solution :(

This is what I want to get:

[image: Expected]

And this is what I have now:

[image: Now]

In my application I use pages.

This is my XAML code for main page (to separate "navigation" panel and "content" panel):

```
<Page x:Class="WpfApp.MainPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignWidth="1920"
      d:DesignHeight="1080" 
      Title="MainPage">

    <Grid>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="95*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <DockPanel Grid.Row="0"
                   Grid.Column="0"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                   Height="Auto"
                   Width="Auto"
                   Margin="15,15,15,0">

            <!-- My controls for select content in listview below -->

        </DockPanel>

        <Frame x:Name="ContentPages" 
               NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"
               Grid.Row="1"
               Margin="15"/>

    </Grid>

</Page>
```

And this is my XAML code for one of the "content" pages:

```
<Page x:Class="WpfApp.AllVideosPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignWidth="1920"
      d:DesignHeight="1080" 
      Title="AllVideosPage">

    <Grid>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ListView Grid.Row="0"
                  Grid.Column="0" 
                  x:Name="ListViewVideos" 
                  VerticalContentAlignment="Top"
                  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                  ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="33*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="33*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="33*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    </Grid>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                            Value="Stretch"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                               Margin="15">
                        <Image Source="{Binding Image}" 
                               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                               VerticalAlignment="Top"
                               Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" 
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                   TextAlignment="Center"
                                   Margin="0,15,0,0"
                                   FontSize="18"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

    </Grid>

</Page>
```

How can I make correct layout? Thanks for any hint.

**EDIT #1:** initial problem solved: I should set `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` to `Disabled` (thanks to @Clemens)

But now my ListView expanding beyond viewable area and that is why I can't scroll it vertically. So, where is a trouble?

**Solved**: I just need to change `<RowDefinition Height="Auto">` of the `Grid` where `ListView` is located to `<RowDefinition Height="*">` value, because `Auto` means "by content size" when `*` means "fill maximum parent size" :)

**P.S.** I change code above, so now it is correct.

Comment: Try `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"`. Besides that, you may want to use a UniformGrid as ItemsPanel.

Comment: It works! But I still can't scroll vertically

Comment: Because I read on the stackoverflow.com that it helps to implement smooth scrolling in WPF. I tried to remove `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"` -- no result.